# Visual Studio 2017 MFC project missing form designer?

Tags: gui, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to get a GUI using Visual C++ MFC template in Visual Studio 2017.
I was watching a YOUTUBE tutorial and when the guy created his template the MFC "form designer" appeared.

When I create a Visual C++ MFC template I can't find the form designer for the life of me.

When I compile, it comes up with the default GUI that is in the template.

How can I get the MFC form designer like the guy in the youtube video.

[My solution File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPXlL.png)

Here is the default GUI, it even has the "TODO" comment just taunting me :)

[Here is the compile result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ0JA.png)

[Here is the YOUTUBE video of the form builder I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYU1z.png)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhx5kJG4GB8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.
Under Resource Files, double click MFCApplication2.rc2

That will show a new window, then double click IDD_MFCAPPLICATION2_DIALOG

Images are below for clarity.

[Visual Studio how to get to design builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvngA.png)

[MFC Design Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9IfX.png)